# How do I cap a circle in SketchUp?

Tags: sketchup

If I have just a circle, without a surface. How do I cap it (create a surface in it) so I can extrude a "solid" cylinder?

I have tried to create a new circle inside with the same radius, but it works sometimes, but mostly not (nothing happens).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out the answer...

To fill "any" outlined polygon (without any surfaces), select the line tool and draw a line along any one segment in the figure. This will fill the polygon with a surface.

So far it has always worked for me.